# Logging a DOM object in a Firefox WebExtension content script prints "<unavailable>"

Tags: javascript, firefox, console.log, firefox-addon-webextensions, browser-extension

I'm building a browser extension with the WebExtension API in FireFox. I'm in the middle of writing a content script, and when I pass any DOM object into `console.log`, it is not printed out.  Instead, I just get the string `<unavailable>`.  Observe:

```
$ console.log(document);
<unavailable>
```

However, I can still access the object's properties.

```
$ console.log(document.baseURI);
https://the_base_uri.com
```

Why does this happen, and what does it mean?

Comment: Without an [mcve] that actually _shows_ your code, it is highly doubtful anyone will be able to explain what is wrong with your code.

Comment: I've also seen `<unavailable>` come up when writing userscripts, and not only when I'm using `console.log`. It's a pretty opaque error

Comment: @CertainPerformance Given that the object and its properties are still accessible, I'm not even certain that it's an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That means that the debugger you're using (presumably the add-on debugger in this case) is attached to a different process than the process where the log message was generated (which would be a web content process in this case).  The MDN page about debugging discusses this in greater detail:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Debugging